# PHP if and statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to add an 'if and' statement, but can't get it working.

```
else if($iamonly == 'Other - ' && trim($othertype == '')) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Error! You selected "Other"</div>';
```

If `$iamonly` field is 'Other' and I enter data in the `$othertype` field, I still get the error message. Please can someone tell me what the heck I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trim` only the variable:

```
if($iamonly == 'Other - ' && trim($othertype) == '') {
```

Comment: Well, this has been upvoted so I assume it should be working. However, it's not working for me.

Comment: Then you need to post what `$iamonly` and `$othertype` is .. post the full input and full `if` statements

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
else if($iamonly == 'Other - ' && trim($othertype == '')) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Error! You selected "Other"</div>';
```

ought to be this:

```
else if($iamonly == 'Other - ' && trim($othertype) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Error! You selected "Other"</div>';
```